# What to use in place of pandas.Series.filter?

Tags: pandas, rapids, cudf

### pandas -> cuDF

Converting some python written for pandas to run on rapids

#### pandas

```
temp=df_train.copy()
temp['buildingqualitytypeid']=temp['buildingqualitytypeid'].fillna(-1)
temp=temp.groupby("buildingqualitytypeid").filter(lambda x: x.buildingqualitytypeid.size > 3)
temp['buildingqualitytypeid'] = temp['buildingqualitytypeid'].replace(-1,np.nan)
print(temp.buildingqualitytypeid.isnull().sum())
print(temp.shape)
```

Anyone know what to use in place of `pandas.Series.filter` for same outcome in `cuDF`?

Comment: Series and groupby `filter` are not currently implemented, but it's likely you could do this example without it. Could you please provide a reproducible example, following https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports or https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're still working on `filter` functionality in `cudf`, but for now the following approach will implement many `filter`-like needs:

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame({'buildingqualitytypeid': np.random.randint(0, 4, 12), 'value': np.arange(12)})
temp=df_train.copy()
temp['buildingqualitytypeid']=temp['buildingqualitytypeid'].fillna(-1)
gtemp=temp.groupby("buildingqualitytypeid").count()
gtemp=gtemp[gtemp['value'] > 3]
gtemp = gtemp.drop('value', axis=1)
gtemp = gtemp.merge(temp.reset_index(), on="buildingqualitytypeid")
gtemp = gtemp.sort_values('index')
gtemp.index = gtemp['index']
gtemp.index.name = None
gtemp = gtemp.drop('index', axis=1)
```

This can be completed considerably more simply if you don't need the `index` values.